# Geometric realisation of smooth $\infty$-stacks

Tags: simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, infinity-topos-theory, differentiable-stacks

Let $Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$ denote the $\infty$-category of sheaves of $\infty$-groupoids over the site $\mathsf{Man}$ of smooth manifolds (if you prefer, that's the model category of simplicial sheaves on $\mathsf{Man}$),
and let $\mathcal S$ denote the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-groupoids (the usual model category of simplicial sets).

The inclusion $\mathcal S\to Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$
admits a left adjoint
$$
\|\cdot\|:Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})\to\mathcal S
$$
called *geometric realisation*.

> Given two morphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ in $Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$
>
> > let us write $f\sim g$ if there exists a (necessarily invertible) 2-morphism $f\Rightarrow g$ in $Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$, and
>
> > let us write $f\approx g$ if there exists a map $h:X\times\mathbb R\to Y$ such that $h|_{X\times\{0\}}\sim f$ and $h|_{X\times\{1\}}\sim g$.

Is it true that for all $M\in\mathsf{Man}$, and all $X\in Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$, the obvious map
$$
\qquad\quad
Hom_{Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})}(M,X)/\approx\quad \to \quad
Hom_{\mathcal S}(\|M\|,\|X\|)/\sim\qquad\quad(*)
$$
is bijective?
[In the RHS of (*), the symbol ∼ just means "homotopic" (and there's only one notion of two morphisms in $\mathcal S$ being homotopic)]

What can be said about the class of objects $M\in Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$ with the property that $\forall X\in Sh^\infty(\mathsf{Man})$ the map $(*)$ is bijective?

Comment: Cue Dmitri Pavlov...

Comment: Have you tried looking around at the stuff on L_R and \Gamma_! etc. in sections 4 and 5 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.12250.pdf ? I think your left hand side computes \pi_0 of L_R(X)(M), but one subtlety is that to turn X into a homotopy invariant *sheaf* you must then also sheafify again after doing L_R (but then you're done- unlike the motivic case you only have to do 'sheafify L_R' once.)

Comment: also maybe there is an error/typo in the statement? you define equivalence relations for maps in Sh(Mfld), but in (*) the right hand side Hom takes place in Spaces not Sh(Mfld).

Comment: @DylanWilson. In the RHS of (*), the symbol $\sim$ just means "homotopic" (and there's only one notion of two morphisms in $\mathcal S$ being homotopic).

Comment: In general, the left hand side of $(\ast)$ is hard to understand: for general $X$, the relation $\approx$ is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski. For general $X$, the relation $\approx$ **is** an equivalence relation. In the world of schemes, it's not an equivalence relation. But in the world of manifolds it is. The proof that it's an equivalence relation uses the existence of a map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that sends $(-\infty,\epsilon)\to 0$ and $(1-\epsilon,\infty)\to 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The case when $M$ is a smooth manifold follows from the [smooth Oka principle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+via+cohesive+path+%E2%88%9E-groupoid#ConsequenceSmoothOkaPrinciple).
See there for an expository account of the argument and references to additional sources.

Indeed, the left side of (*) is $$\def\Hom{\mathop{\rm Hom}} π_0(ʃ\Hom(M,X)),$$
whereas the right side of (*) is $$π_0(\Hom(ʃM,ʃX)),$$
where $ʃ$ denotes the [shape functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+modality),
which is called “geometric realization” in the main post and is denoted by $‖{-}‖$ there.
(From my point of view, a geometric realization functor converts a categorical object like a simplicial set to a geometric object like a topological space, whereas a shape functor converts a geometric object like a sheaf of simplicial sets on manifolds to a categorical object like a simplicial set.)

Concerning the case of a general $M$,
not much can be expected if $M$ has homotopy groups in degree 1 or higher
(meaning $M$ is not weakly equivalent to a sheaf of sets on manifolds).
For example, taking $M=N/\!/G$ to be the stacky quotient of a manifold by an action of a Lie group, and $X$ to be the stack given by the homotopy group completion of the sheaf of symmetric monoidal groupoids of vector bundles,
the left side of (*) computes the equivariant K-theory of $M$ (basically, it boils down to Segal's model),
whereas the right side computes the Borel equivariant K-theory of $M=N/\!/G$.
These two are different in general.